# Is const_casting a mutable field safe?

Tags: c++, constants, c++03

Consider the following C++03 program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    mutable int x;

    T() : x(0) {}
};

void bar(int& x)
{
   x = 42;
}

void foo(const T& t)
{
   bar(const_cast<int&>(t.x));
}

int main()
{
   T t;
   foo(t);
   std::cout << t.x << '\n';
}
```

It [appears to work](http://ideone.com/MU0mQc), but is it safe for sure?

I'm only modifying a `mutable` field, but having stripped away its `const` context entirely makes me nervous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is safe, but also unnecessary.  Because of the `mutable`, `t.x` is already of type `int&`.  Your example program [works fine if the cast is removed entirely](http://ideone.com/Fs7IkH).

Comment: Oh darn it.. I failed to upload to my compilation server the header change where I made the field `mutable` in my real project, and as such I missed that the field is already of a non-`const` type. Rendering this whole question rather moot... Hehe. Thanks :)